# Pandas replace string using values from list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace string in one the columns inside my dataframe(df). Here's what df looks like:

```
                           0                  1
0  2012 Black Toyota Corolla    White/Black/Red
1      2013 Red Toyota Camry    Red
2      2015 Blue Honda Civic    Blue
3         2012 Black Mazda 6    Black/Red/White
4   2011 White Nissan Maxima    White/Red/Black
```

Sometimes, column 1 has multiple color values, sometimes only a single value. I would like to take however many values there are in column 1, check if any of those exist in column 0 and remove that value from column 0.

I've tried approaching it this way.

```py
    def removeColor(main,sub):
         for i in sub.split('/'):
                 main = main.str.replace(i, '')
         return(main)
```

```
>>> df['0'] = df['0'].map(lambda x: removeColor(x['0'],x['2']))
```

This results in a TypeError.

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

My expected output looks like below:

```
                     0                  1
0  2012 Toyota Corolla    White/Black/Red
1    2013 Toyota Camry    Red
2     2015 Honda Civic    Blue
3         2012 Mazda 6    Black/Red/White
4   2011 Nissan Maxima    White/Red/Black
```

Comment: How does column 1 have more values in your expected output?

Comment: @Erfan, Sorry about that. I've fixed column 1.

Comment: `df['0'].str.replace('|'.join(df.iloc[:,1].str.replace('/','|')),'')` ?

Comment: The original csv that I'm using for the dataframe has the values 0,1 as strings. Referring to them as df[0] doesn't work. It could easily have been Title, Colors instead of 0,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` only works on a Series. In your `lambda` function, `x` would be a String (the value for column "0"), so when you do `x["0"]` and `x["1"]` it's trying to get the index from a String, hence your error.

The [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function lets you act on an entire row (or column) and would be better suited. Here's one way to accomplish what you're after:

```
import re

def remove_color(row):
    return re.sub(row.iloc[1].replace("/", "|"), "", row.iloc[0]).replace("  ", " ")


df.iloc[:, 0] = df.apply(remove_color, axis=1)
```

You could replace the `iloc` calls with specific column names to make it more readable (you mentioned col names could be anything so I'm giving a generic approach here).

The second `replace` call is to remove extra spaces that were left by the `re.sub`. You could modify your `re.sub` to do that on a single call, but it could get messy.

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: @JasonBourne Updated the answer including why your approach didn't work. Feel free to accept and/or upvote this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

iLoc = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['2012 Black Toyota Corolla','2013 Red Toyota Camry','2015 Blue Honda Civic','2012 Black Mazda 6','2011 White Nissan Maxima'],'1': ['White/Black/Red','Red','Blue','Black/Red/White','White/Red/Black']})

display(iLoc)

def removeColor(main,sub):
    for i in range(len(main)):
        for j in str(sub[i]).split('/'):
            main[i] = main[i].replace(j, '').replace('  ',' ').strip()
    return main

iLoc["0"] = removeColor(iLoc["0"],iLoc["1"])

display(iLoc)
```

Your method was partially correct. 
You need to extract value from the series and replace each main row with its substring row from same index